# Why does S3 change content type of my CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, vue.js, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm using ruby on rails to generate presigned url so I can upload a CSV file. This works perfectly, I can even get the CSV using a presigned URL. The problem is when I get the CSV file a random block of text appears at the top of the csv.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryrnmGKBwtkSrSvPUR
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="MOCK_DATA.csv"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,job_title,city,country
1,Emlyn,Dayce,edayce0@example.com,Male,Quality Control Specialist,Debrecen,Hungary
```

So when I try to loop through the csv using the below code:

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

csv = CSV.new(open(presigned_url), headers: false)

csv.each do |csv|
  puts csv.to_s
end
```

I get the following error:

```
CSV::MalformedCSVError (Illegal quoting in line 2.):
```

Which is refering to the line:

```
csv.each do |csv|
```

Any solutions on a: how to remove this block of text before looping / while parsing the CSV. Or better yet preventing the block of text from being added in the first place using S3 Presigned URLs.

Note: I have tried to add

```
content_type: 'text/csv'
```

to presigned request, however, it doesn't recognize the param.

**UPLOADING PROCESS:**

I am using Vuejs to upload the csv to S3.

```
let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", this.$refs.file.files[0], { contentType: 'text/csv' 
});

  this.axios
    .put(this.presigned_url, formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      // Handle response
      if(response.status == 200){
        this.original_file_name = "Processing CSV..."
        this.processCsv();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Don't use open-uri. Use an actual http client such as [Net:HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html). http://sakurity.com/blog/2015/02/28/openuri.html

Comment: @max Thanks for the suggestion I'm using httparty instead also tried Net:HTTP but no luck, unfortunately.  If I check the CSV on the AWS server it looks like it has the meta text at the top still so it must get added at the upload stages I'm thinking.

Comment: That string is not random - its http headers so something here is either sending a malformed request or parsing a request wrong.

Comment: Hi @CodeCabin, have you got any solution on that?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue, the problem is that you are sending the entire form into S3 and not just the file.

A correct code snippet in your case would be something like this:

```
this.axios
  .put(this.presigned_url, this.$refs.file.files[0], {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    // Handle response
    if(response.status == 200){
      this.original_file_name = "Processing CSV..."
      this.processCsv();
    }
  });
```